# Copy Records to another Screen in acumatica

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

I have 2 screen, inquiry and data entry.
and i want to copy Record from Screen1 to screen2, see picture below.
[scree1 and Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdwt5.png)

I use the following code:

```
public PXAction<FuncLocFilter> CreateFuncLoc;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Functional Location")]
    protected virtual void createFuncLoc()
    {
        FuncLocFilter row = Filter.Current;
        BSMTFuncLoc FnLc = new BSMTFuncLoc();

        FunLocEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<FunLocEntry>();
        graph.FunLocations.Current.FuncLocCD = row.FuncLocCD;
        graph.FunLocations.Current.StructureID = row.StructureID;
        graph.FunLocations.Current.HierLevels = row.HierLevels;
        graph.FunLocations.Current.EditMask = row.EditMask;
        if (graph.FunLocations.Current != null)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "Functional Location");
        }
    }
```

but i encountered an error like the following:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N7aP.png)

can someone please help solve this seemingly stupid question?

im sorry my english is bad.. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a common pattern to create data records via code/programming in Acumatica

```
    public PXAction<FuncLocFilter> CreateFuncLoc;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Functional Location")]
    protected virtual void createFuncLoc()
    {
        FuncLocFilter row = Filter.Current;

        // 1. Create an instance of the BLC (graph)
        FunLocEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<FunLocEntry>();

        // 2. Create an instance of the BSMTFuncLoc DAC, set key field values (besides the ones whose values are generated by the system), 
        //    and insert the record into the cache
        BSMTFuncLoc FnLc = new BSMTFuncLoc();
        FnLc.FuncLocCD = row.FuncLocCD;
        FnLc = graph.FunLocations.Insert(FnLc);

        // 3. Set non-key field values and update the record in the cache
        FnLc.StructureID = row.StructureID;
        FnLc.HierLevels = row.HierLevels;
        FnLc.EditMask = row.EditMask;
        FnLc = graph.FunLocations.Update(FnLc);

        // 4. Redirect
        if (graph.FunLocations.Current != null)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "Functional Location");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggest it's work for me @DChhapgar